# New VS2015 blank app fails to launch on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2015

I'm running Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview build 10130 and Visual Studio 2015 RC.
When I create a new solution using the Blank App template and try to run it, it fails with a message: Unable to activate Windows Store app ''. The activation request failed with error 'The wait operation timed out'.
Any ideas what could be causing it?

Comment: Have you updated Win 10 from an earlier build since installing VS2015? I had weird problems after installing 10130, and I fixed this by doing a repair on VS2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that rebooting the computer solved the problem.

Comment: This also worked for me, but there should be some better solution. :(